# Error "firebase.database is not a function" en Vue cli

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, firebase, vue.js, npm

Estoy tratando de conectar una base de datos Firebase desde un proyecto en VueJS, el problema es que arroja el siguiente error: "firebase.database is not a function".
He leído que hay que modificar el src del script de firebase para solucionarlo, pero en mi caso no instalé firebase con la etiqueta script, sino que lo instalé con npm en el cli de VueJS.
Agrego el código JS:

````
  import config from '@/assets/js/config'
  let app = firebase.initializeApp(config); 
  let db = app.database();
  let websitesRef = db.ref('websites');```

el archivo config.js tiene los datos de la base de datos como se muestra a continuación:

``` apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "" ```
````